# Angular 2 unit test reducers keep changes

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I'm starting learning Angular 2 and unit tests and I have some issues when testing reducers and then, later on, trying to test a component that also uses the reducer.

The problem, since I'm testing if the dispatch function is working, the changes made on the store are persisting and making other test fail.

This is my code:

*reducer.spec.ts*

```
it('should dispatch action DATA_FETCH', () => {
    const mockData = [
        { id: 0, name: 'Name 01' },
        { id: 1, name: 'Name 02' }
    ];

    const mockInitial = {
        ..._data,
        customers: mockData
    };

    _store.dispatch({
        type: DATA_FETCH,
        payload: mockData
    });

    expect(_data).toEqual(mockInitial);
});

// This test pass
```

And then I'm trying to test a component that share the same data from this store, like this:

```
it('should have initial value array to be empty', () => {
    expect(component.customers).toEqual([]);
});
```

But I keep getting an error like this:

> Expected [ Object({ id: 0, name: 'Name 01' }, { id: 1, name: 'Name 02' }) ] to equal [  ]

Is there a way to destroy/clear the store after I finish the tests within that part?

---

I think the reason why I'm getting this error is because I'm using a TestModule, which basically is a "clone" module of my main module, this way I don't need to declare the same thing multiple times for each test I'm running. The store, for example, instead of configure it in every test I have, I have it configured on this TestModule and then just import this on my unit tests. Maybe this is the reason, but I don't know how to solve it.